# GAWK Syntax Issue

Tags: awk

Can someone help me out with this syntax issue?

```sh
bash-4.2$ cat test_gawk | gawk -F, '{if($1 ~/STOP/ && ($21 ~ /722/) print $21, " "$34, " "$31, " "$64}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n
```

It looks like I am receiving the syntax error when it comes time to print output.

Comment: missing closing parenthesis of `if`  Syntax error should capture it as well.

Comment: @karakfa it gives me: gawk: cmd. line:1: then on print line ^ syntax error

Comment: `^` should be pointing to the error location.

Comment: @karakfa yes it points on start of print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is caused by the spurious opening `(` for the second condition in the if-statement.

As people have already pointed out in the comments above:

> In awk, the form of an if-statement is typically `if(){}`

So, your own invocation needs to look like **this**:

```
gawk -F, '{if($1 ~/STOP/ && $21 ~ /722/){print $21, " "$34, " "$31, " "$64}}'
```

**Not this**:

```
gawk -F, '{if($1 ~/STOP/ && $21 ~ /722/) print $21, " "$34, " "$31, " "$64}'
```

Another comment on the side:  if you find yourself using `cat` with a single filename you're most likely doing it wrong.  So, the better choice would be:

```
gawk -F, '{if($1 ~/STOP/ && ($21 ~ /722/){print $21, " "$34, " "$31, " "$64}}' test_gawk | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: technically, legacy compatibility does allow for the strange syntax like if (something) just-do-it-no-brackets. The OP errror'ed out not on { } but on forgetting to close the second ) for the if condition. that said . it's very awkward symtax for awk seeing that it's a lot closer cousin to C/C++ than to python syntax.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto - ooops; you're quite right. Amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help @tink